# legacy opengl - enabling/disabling texture types

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

I analyze the following legacy opengl code:

```
GLboolean textur2d; 
glIsEnabled(texture2d, GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLboolean rectangleNV; 
glIsEnabled(rectangleNV, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV);

GLboolean texture3d; 
glIsEnabled(texture3d, GL_TEXTURE_3D);

GLboolean cubeMap; 
glIsEnabled(cubeMap,GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
///some drawing

if(!texture2d)
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
if(rectangleNV)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV);
if(texture3d)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
if(cubeMap)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)
```

As you can see before drawing texture 2d other texture types are disabled. Is it necessary in legacy opengl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code follows the principle of being a good guest and cleaning up behind itself. Since OpenGL is a state machine, it might be, that this code is called from a place that expects the state machine being in the same state after the code ran as it was before.

There's a certain precedence of texturing targets, and if you want to use 2D textures, having 3D, cubes and rectangles enabled would interfere with that, so you've to disable them first. But then, once you're done, you revert the state.

It's good practice, especially within libraries and plugins.

Comment: Should I also disable other texture types when drawing texture 2d using modern opengl with shaders ?

Comment: @Irbis: You don't have to (with a conforming implementation). The texture target sampled from is determined by the type of the sampler used.